Better way to create these on Tailwind CSS
I learned to use @apply it's not recommendable but how can I create this class without @apply ?
this is in the index.css file
@layer components {
    .desktop-grid {
        @apply  
            lg:grid
            lg:grid-cols-[1fr,repeat(12,84px),1fr]
            lg:mx-auto
            lg:gap-x-6;
                  }
}

Seartching on the web

import numpy as np

def min_diff_partition(arr):

  n = len(arr)
  total_sum = np.sum(arr)
  target_sum = total_sum // 2

  
  dp = np.ones((n + 1, target_sum + 1)) * float('inf')

  dp[0, 0] = 0

  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, target_sum + 1):
      if arr[i - 1] <= j:
        dp[i, j] = min(dp[i - 1, j], dp[i - 1, j - arr[i - 1]] + arr[i - 1])
      else:
        dp[i, j] = dp[i - 1, j]


  return dp[n, target_sum]


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Not an answer: the question is in CSS, this Python code is not related in any way to the question.
